# Как вынести лучшие рекорды игры в другой контроллер?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

У меня есть ViewController из которого можно перейти в Start Game и Records и мне нужно обработать топ 3 рекорда из игры в контроллер Records

Код и GameViewController

```
    import UIKit
    import seibmarineGames.GameViewControllerDelegate
    class GameViewController: UIViewController {
        private let minY: CGFloat = 390
        private let maxY: CGFloat = 750
        weak var delegate: GameViewControllerDelegate?
        var score = 0
        var timer: Timer?
        var score1: Int = 0
        var score2: Int = 0
        var score3: Int = 0
        
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var backGround: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var boatTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var boatOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var sharkOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var sharkTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var submarine: UIImageView!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            scoreLabel.textColor = .white
            scoreLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(increaseScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
            let submarineImage = UIImage(named: "submarine")
            self.submarine.image = submarineImage
            let boatOneImage = UIImage(named: "boat1")
            self.boatOne.image = boatOneImage
            let boatTwoImage = UIImage(named: "boat2")
            self.boatTwo.image = boatTwoImage
            let sharkOneImage = UIImage(named: "shark1")
            self.sharkOne.image = sharkOneImage
            let sharkTwoImage = UIImage(named: "shark2")
            self.sharkTwo.image = sharkTwoImage
            let backGroundImage = UIImage(named: "background")
            self.backGround.image = backGroundImage
    
            animateSharkOne()
            animateSharkTwo()
            animateBoatOne()
            animateBoatTwo()
            let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        }
    
        @objc func increaseScore() {
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            if score > score1 {
                   score3 = score2
                   score2 = score1
                   score1 = score
               } else if score > score2 {
                   score3 = score2
                   score2 = score
               } else if score > score3 {
                   score3 = score
               }
            delegate?.gameViewController(self, didUpdateTopScores: [score1, score2, score3])
        }
    
        @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            if let submarinePresentation = submarine.layer.presentation(),
               let boatOnePresentation = boatOne.layer.presentation(),
               let boatTwoPresentation = boatTwo.layer.presentation(),
               let sharkOnePresentation = sharkOne.layer.presentation(),
               let sharkTwoPresentation = sharkTwo.layer.presentation(),
               (submarinePresentation.frame.intersects(boatOnePresentation.frame)
                || submarinePresentation.frame.intersects(boatTwoPresentation.frame)
                || submarinePresentation.frame.intersects(sharkOnePresentation.frame)
                || submarinePresentation.frame.intersects(sharkTwoPresentation.frame)) {
                endGame()
            } else {
                if sender.state == .changed {
                    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
                    let newY = submarine.frame.origin.y + translation.y
                    if newY >= minY && newY <= maxY {
                        submarine.frame.origin.y = newY
                    }
                    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
                }
            }
        }
    
        private func animateSharkOne() {
            let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 5.0
            self.sharkOne.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 500)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
                self.sharkOne.frame.origin.x -= 600
            } completion: { _ in
                self.animateSharkOne()
            }
        }
    
        private func animateSharkTwo() {
            let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 3.5
            sharkTwo.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 670)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
                self.sharkTwo.frame.origin.x -= 600
            } completion: { _ in
                self.animateSharkTwo()
            }
        }
    
        private func animateBoatOne() {
            let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 7.0
            boatOne.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 370)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
                self.boatOne.frame.origin.x -= 600
            } completion: { _ in
                self.animateBoatOne()
            }
        }
    
        private func animateBoatTwo() {
            let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 5.0
            boatTwo.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 450, y: 380)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
                self.boatTwo.frame.origin.x -= 600
            } completion: { _ in
                self.animateBoatTwo()
            }
        }
    
        private func endGame() {
            let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestartViewController") as! RestartViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
        
        deinit {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        func gameViewController(_ viewController: GameViewController, didUpdateTopScores scores: [Int]) {
            topScores = scores
            updateScoreLabels()
        }
    }
```

Код из Records

```
    import UIKit
    
    class RecordsViewController: UIViewController, GameViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        @IBOutlet var score1Label: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var score2Label: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var score3Label: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var image1: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet var image2: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet var image3: UIImageView!
        var topScores: [Int] = [0, 0, 0]
        var imageViews: [UIImageView] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            imageViews = [image1, image2, image3]
               updateScoreLabels()
        }
        private func updateScoreLabels() {
            for (index, score) in topScores.enumerated() {
                let scoreLabel = index == 0 ? score1Label : index == 1 ? score2Label : score3Label
                scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            }
        }
        private func showImagePicker(forImageView imageView: UIImageView) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        
    extension RecordsViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
            func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                  
                    if image1.isFirstResponder {
                        image1.image = selectedImage
                    } else if image2.isFirstResponder {
                        image2.image = selectedImage
                    } else if image3.isFirstResponder {
                        image3.image = selectedImage
                    }
                }
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    
        
        @IBAction func addPhotoFor1Record(_ sender: Any) {
            showImagePicker(forImageView: image1)
        }
        
        @IBAction func addPhotoFor2Record(_ sender: Any) {
            showImagePicker(forImageView: image2)
        }
        @IBAction func addPhotoFor3Record(_ sender: Any) {
            showImagePicker(forImageView: image3)
        }
        
    }
```

Я так же создал файл GameViewControllerDelegate.swift

```
import Foundation
    
    protocol GameViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
        func gameViewController(_ viewController: GameViewController, didUpdateTopScores scores: [Int])
    }
```

Код из ViewController

```
    import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
          
        }
        @IBAction func startButtonPressed() {
            let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController") as! GameViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
        @IBAction func recordButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecordsViewController") as! RecordsViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
```

[image: контроллеры]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.